# Have Qt Creator execute gdb command after all libraries are loaded

Tags: 14.04, c++, qt-creator, gdb

I would like to setup Qt Creator debugger to ignore all boost files when stepping through my code. Just to test, I added the command:

> `"skip file /usr/include/boost/ptr_container/ptr_sequence/adapter.hpp"`

to the Additional Startup Commands in `Tools>Options>Debugger>GDB`. I recieve the following output:

```
&"skip file /usr/include/boost/ptr_container/ptr_sequence_adapter.hpp\n"

&"No source file named /usr/include/boost/ptr_container/ptr_sequence_adapter.hpp.\n"
~"Ignore file pending future shared library load? (y or [n]) [answered N; input not from terminal]\n"
```

I am looking for a way in Qt Creator to have it execute my command after all libraries have been loaded automatically or away to have gdb select [y] for Ignore file pending future shared library load.

Comment: I proposed a [patch](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18531) to gdb, but I still think adding the functionality to Qt Creator to apply commands after every thing has finished loading is of value.